# Add files to build directory in Flutter

Tags: flutter

When I type `flutter build web` I want a custom python script to be added to the build directory found under

```
[Project-dir]/web/script.py
```

And I want this file to be copied to

```
[Project-dir]/build/web/script.py
```

How can I tell flutter to do this?

I am using vscode

Comment: PS. I want this because the build directory is excluded from source control

Answer (score 0):

i had the same question as you, and after searching for a while i got to this:

create a folder that contains what you want

add your the relative path to pubspec.yaml in the assets section

```
...

flutter:
 assets:
    - [relative_path]

...
```

and voila, when you build your app again, a folder will be included in /data/flutter_assets/[your_directory] and it will contain everything you want